# perspective raycasting

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, visualization, raycasting

can someone point me to some methods for perspective ray casting. I have seen ray splitting techniques. What other casting methods are available? Which one is easiest to implement?

Comment: Best to add a link to a paper or something -- "perspective ray casting" doesn't mean anything in particular, even to most specialists.  I'm familiar with computer graphics and ray tracing, but I had to do a google search to guess that you're asking about aliasing problems with voxel-based scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this [Ray-Casting Tutorial For Game Development And Other Purposes by F. Permadi](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/index.html). It describes the easiest method. It was also described in the [Tricks of the Game-Programming Gurus book by André LaMothe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672305070).

I've implemented it several times. Takes ~1K lines of code or less (depending on your programming language and how advanced you want your raycaster to be). Basic school math.

Comment: I do not see where this discusses the problems arising with perspective raycasting. It is just the basic description.

Comment: What problems are you talking about?

Comment: the problem that in standard perspective raycasting voxel coverage gets bad if you are far away from the near plane. i search an efficient way to avoid this. there are some suggested old methods like ray splitting etc. But i was wondering if there is something more recent.

Comment: You probably want to explain the problem in the question. Otherwise you're likely to get randomish answers, kind of like mine. Is it the oversampling problem (1 screen pixel covers many texture pixels)?